# Getting /Accounts/['ACCOUNT_SID]/Messages.json not found error while working with Twilio

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I searched for similar issues but couldn't find a satisfying answer.
Here's the python snippet that I am using to send messages from my Twilio verified number to my registered mobile number:

```
account_sid = ['AC02ba1e07c83130f76679f2f334160fba']
auth_token = ['*******************************']
client = Client(account_sid,auth_token)

message = client.messages \
            .create(
                body=sent,
                from_='my_twilio_mobile_number',
                to='my_reg_mobile_number'
            )
print(message.sid)
```

Upon executing, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ameeteshsharma/Documents/covax/avail.py", line 59, in <module>
  message = client.messages \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twilio/rest/api/v2010/account/message/__init__.py", line 88, in create
  payload = self._version.create(method='POST', uri=self._uri, data=data, )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/twilio/base/version.py", line 205, in create
  raise self.exception(method, uri, response, 'Unable to create record')
  twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: 
 HTTP Error Your request was:

 POST /Accounts/['AC02ba1e07c83130f76679f2f334160fba']/Messages.json

 Twilio returned the following information:

 Unable to create record: The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/['AC02ba1e07c83130f76679f2f334160fba']/Messages.json was not found

 More information may be available here:

 https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404
```

I tried looking at the aforementioned docs, but couldn't find a reasonable solution. The account_sid and auth_token are both correct. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the mistake is that you're declaring both `account_sid` and `auth_token` as `list` and they should be `string`:

```py
account_sid = 'AC02ba1e07c83130f76679f2f334160fba'
auth_token = '*******************************'
client = Client(account_sid,auth_token)
```